# What the difference between a Ruby class level variable and a Rails class_attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any difference between a class level variable (`@@something`), and defining a `class_attribute` (https://apidock.com/rails/Class/class_attribute) in Rails?

For example, in these two code snippets, will there be any difference in behaviour?

```
class Adaptee
  def self.adapter=(adapter)
    @@adapter = adapter
  end
end
```

```
class Adaptee
  class_attribute :adapter
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most important difference is that `class_attribute` is not inherit.

For example we have:

```
class Parent
  class_attribute :klass_atr
  @@klass_var = :foo

  class << self
    def klass_atr
      :foo
    end

    def klass_var
      @@klass_var
    end

    def klass_var=(klass_var)
      @@klass_var = klass_var
    end
  end
end

class Child < Parent; end
```

When we assign class variable in `Сhild` we change it in `Parent` too:

```
Child.klass_var = :bar
Parent.klass_var # => :bar
```

But when we use `class_attribute`, we don't:

```
Child.klass_atr = :bar
Parent.klass_atr # => :foo
```

That's why most popular Ruby style guide [doesn't recommend](https://rubystyle.guide/#no-class-vars) to use class variables.